# How do I pass 2 items in to a function by reference without changing the first item

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I know how to pass by reference, but I need to pass 1 item in, do some code. Then later on, call the same function, passing in something else. When I call the 2nd time, it's adding changes to the first one. Here's my code:

```
map<string, int> wordsHam;
map<string, int> wordsSpam;

void insert(map<string, int> &words, string word)
  {
      if(words.find(word) != words.end())
          words[word]++;
      else
          words.insert(map<string,int>::value_type(word,1));
  }
//in main.cpp
ifstream training_ham(argv[1]);
    if(training_ham.is_open()){
      while(getline(training_ham, message)){
         string word;
         stringstream extract(message);
         while(extract >> word){
            num_words_ham ++;
            insert(wordsHam, word); //called here
         }
        num_messages_ham++;
      }
    training_ham.close();
    }
```

Now when I repeat the above code with a different file and call insert(wordsSpam, word), my wordsHam is filled with appropriate values plus the values that are supposed to be in wordsSpam. I have to pass by reference so they're changed when the function's done, but the second time isn't the same map. Any help please?

Thanks

Comment: Remember that the `operator[]` function of `std::map` will create and insert the key and (default/zero initialized) value if it doesn't exist in the map. That means you don't have to use `find` or `insert`. Plain `words[word]++` will work for both updating and inserting with the correct value.

Comment: As for your problem, just call the function with the correct object?

Comment: Ah that's good to know for shortening up my code. Ah nvm, I saw my problem. Yeah called it with the right object, but miscalculated values on paper, thought they were copied from the other map, sorry. Thanks for your reply